# How can I speed up this 2m5s query that has indices?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

How can I speed up this 2m5s query that has indices?

```
select urls.id as urlId, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 0 then 1 end) as aCount, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 1 then 1 end) as bCount, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 2 then 1 end) as cCount, 
    count(distinct s1.source_id) as sourcesCount 
from urls join stats s1 on urls.id = s1.url_id 
where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12' 
group by urls.id 
order by aCount desc 
limit 0,100;

mysql> show create table stats;

| stats | CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hit_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `hit_type` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `url_id_idx` (`url_id`),
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`),
  KEY `stats_hit_date_idx` (`hit_date`),
  CONSTRAINT `stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `urls` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `stats_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `sources` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6027557 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

mysql> describe select...
| id | select_type | table   | type   | possible_keys                                                                                   | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows    | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1      | ALL    | url_id_idx,stats_hit_date_idx                                                                   | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                     | 5869695 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | urls    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,urls_email_idx,urls_status_idx,deptId_idx,deptId_status_email_idx                       | PRIMARY | 102     | db.s1.url_id             |     1   | Using index                                  |
```

It doesn't seem to be using the hit_date index or url_id index.

I tried using a sub-select `(select count(*) from stats where url_id = ... and hit_date >= ... and hit_type = 0) as aCount` and it was faster and took 24s. Is there a way to make it less than 5s? The limit for the entire request is 30s.

MySQL Server version:         5.6.35-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Is `hit_date >= '2017-12-12'` the majority of the table? Test an compound index (hit_date, url_id). Can url_id be made shorter?

Comment: `hit_date` value will be by default 1 year ago. It could be any value from 1 year ago until today.  I will try a compound index, with first 10 chars of url_id.

Comment: "It could be any value from 1 year" sounds like `hit_date >= '2017-12-12'` is the entire table.

Comment: is your innodb_buffer_pool_size sufficient to contain most of these tables?

Comment: The pattern `count(case when s1.hit_type = 0 then 1 end)` could be simplified to `count(s1.hit_type = 0)` however will be no performance difference.

Comment: I added a multi-index `alter table stats add index stats_url_id_hit_date_idx (url_id(10), hit_date);` but `describe select...` still shows it not using an index `|  1 | SIMPLE      | s1      | ALL    | url_id_idx,stats_hit_date_idx,stats_url_id_hit_date_idx                                   | NULL | ...` (The last column name here is `key`.) Yes technically `hit_date >= '2017-12-12` is the entire table as the table is only a few months old. However, even `describe select...` with `hit_date >= '2012-12-01'` shows no index used and the query takes 24s.

Comment: @danblack I was playing with that before and actually it is `sum(s1.hit_type = 0)` because count would add up both 0 and 1 but sum will only add up 1's. `select hit_type=0` returns 0 on false and 1 on true.

Comment: "That has indices" -- But are they optimal?

Comment: @danblack - not `count...`, but `SUM(s1.hit_type = 0)`

Comment: @Chloe - "Index prefixes" are virtually useless, especially when they are not last in a composite index.  `hit_date` won't be used in your suggested index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is equal to

```
select /* urls.id */ s1.url_id as urlId, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 0 then 1 end) as aCount, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 1 then 1 end) as bCount, 
    count(case when s1.hit_type = 2 then 1 end) as cCount, 
    count(distinct s1.source_id) as sourcesCount 
from /* urls join */ stats s1 /* on urls.id = s1.url_id */
where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12' 
group by /* urls.id */ s1.url_id
order by aCount desc 
limit 0,100;
```

except in your query output there are only records which "pairs" exists in `urls` table.

But the constraint

```
CONSTRAINT `stats_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`url_id`) REFERENCES `urls` (`ID`)
```

do not allow those records.

So my query is absolutely equal to your one, and you can use it instead.

To increase this query speed you may create covering index

```
ALTER TABLE stats ADD INDEX idx (url_id, hit_date, hit_type, source_id)
```

And the best way is to move `url_id` to a separate table and replace it with a reference of numeric type (grouping by VARCHAR field is expensive).

---

Additionally - `count(case when s1.hit_type = N then 1 end)` can be replaced with short `SUM(s1.hit_type = N)`.

---

To speed up the whole query I'd recommend try to divide it to 4 separate queries:

```
SELECT urlId, 
       MAX(aCount) aCount, 
       MAX(bCount) bCount, 
       MAX(cCount) cCount, 
       MAX(sourcesCount) sourcesCount 
FROM (  select  s1.url_id as urlId, 
                COUNT(*) as aCount, 
                0 as bCount, 
                0 as cCount, 
                0 as sourcesCount 
        from stats s1 
        where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12' AND s1.hit_type = 0
        group by s1.url_id
      UNION ALL
        select  s1.url_id, 0, COUNT(*), 0, 0
        from stats s1 
        where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12'  AND s1.hit_type = 1
        group by s1.url_id
      UNION ALL
        select  s1.url_id as urlId, 0, 0, COUNT(*), 0
        from stats s1 
        where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12'  AND s1.hit_type = 2
        group by s1.url_id
      UNION ALL
        select  s1.url_id as urlId, 0, 0, 0, count(distinct s1.source_id)
        from stats s1 
        where s1.hit_date >= '2017-12-12' 
        group by s1.url_id
    ) x
GROUP BY urlId
order by aCount desc 
limit 0,100;
```

The index by `(url_id, hit_type, hit_date)` will speed up first 3 subqueries, and by `(url_id, hit_date, source_id)` will speed up the last subquery.

Comment: You are right. I am actually only selecting from one table. It reduced the time to 8.4s! I'll take it. The index did not help. The `sum()` expression did not help. The multi-query + `UNION` is genius! But alas, it took 25s instead. Even with the last 2 indices. Each sub-query takes about 6s.

Comment: @Chloe *But alas* That didn't surprise me. The solution optimal in one case can be absolutely unapplicable in another case. For this reason, I have considered several different possibilities. Only practical tests can help in select the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your query depends on wanting to get a summary after reading 5869695+ results and matching these in another table.

Getting this in < 5 seconds is a large ask.

As it seems your data is fairly constant after entry I'd suggest creating summary tables based on date and having a {a,b,c}Count.